# List to JSON Object

Tags: python, json

I am being returned data in this form:

```
['{\n  "data": {\n    "promoter": {\n      "instagram_id": 123,\n      "instagram_name": "user",\n      "instagram_token": "\\"123\\"",\n      "location": "sydney",\n      "profile_pic": "profile/pic.jpg",\n      "user_id": 1,\n      "username": "my_user_name"\n    },\n    "success": true\n  }\n}']
```

I am confused as to how I can convert this into a `JSON object` such that I can do:

`json_obj['data']['promoter']['instagram_id']`

I have tried converting the `list` into a `JSON String` with `dumps` and then using `loads` but to no avail.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert only the first element of the list, with `json.loads`. Demo:

```
>>> data = ['{\n  "data": {\n    "promoter": {\n      "instagram_id": 123,\n      "instagram_name": "user",\n      "instagram_token": "\\"123\\"",\n      "location": "sydney",\n      "profile_pic": "profile/pic.jpg",\n      "user_id": 1,\n      "username": "my_user_name"\n    },\n    "success": true\n  }\n}']
>>> import json
>>> json_obj = json.loads(data[0])
>>> json_obj['data']['promoter']['instagram_id']
123
```

Comment: Thanks Regis. I was doing `json.loads(data)` and being hit with an error that I needed to provide a `string`.

Comment: @Giri seems like that should have been a clue!